# Will a general function $\phi:[1,\infty)\rightarrow (0,1)$ have an infinite product of $0$?

Tags: functions, convergence-divergence, proof-writing, infinite-product

Let $\phi:[1,\infty)\rightarrow (0,1)$. Is $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\prod^n_{i=1}\phi(i)=0$? If so, could this be proven? I specifically have the function
\begin{equation}
\phi(m)=1-\frac{2\lfloor\log_2(f(m))\rfloor}{f(m)}\cdot \frac{F_{2m+1}}{F_{2m+2}}
\end{equation}

where $f(m)=\frac{3^{m}\left(n+1\right)}{2^{m}}-1$ such that $n\in\{1,2,3,4,...\}$ and $F_{\zeta}$ is the Fibonacci number at $\zeta$. Instead of dealing which a complicated infinite product, it would be desirable to answer the first queation (i.e. with a general function). I have not specified whether $\phi$ is an injection or surjection (but if it makes the problem easier, I would lean towards an injection). Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, yes I'll edit the original.

Comment: For the question in the title, $e^{-1/x^2}$ has limit different from zero. I don't know about your particular function though.

Comment: We have $$\phi(m)=1-\mathcal{O}_n\left(\frac{m}{(3/2)^m}\right) \quad \text{as} \quad m \to \infty,$$ with the implicit bound depending only on $n$. So the product will converge to a positive real number, unless $\phi(m) = 0$ for some $m$.

Comment: @SangchulLee _because_ $\sum\frac m{(3/2)^m}<\infty$.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @SangchulLee, could that positive real number be explicitly defined or at least bounded by an inequality?

Comment: @AnilCh Are you saying that $\phi(x)=e^{-1/x^2}$? If so, that doesn't comply with the mapping.

Comment: The reason is essentially the same as that progressively adding positive numbers may lead to a convergent series. (To see why, take the logarithm to the product!) As for the exact value, such as an elementary closed form, of the infinite product, I don't have any idea and I would be very surprised if it has such one. Even the toy version $\prod_{m=1}^{\infty}(1 - x^m)$ is related to a very important number-theoretic function called the Dirichlet eta function, which is surprisingly complicated and rich in structure.

Comment: What do you mean with 'that doesn't comply with the mapping'? It's defined in $[1, \infty)$ and it has its image in the interval $(0,1)$, and the limit of the product is not zero.

Comment: @SangchulLee Thank you very much!

Comment: @AnilCh Sorry, it's late and I read it as $e^{1/x^2}$, lol

Comment: @SangchulLee Could $\phi(x)$ be defined in terms of a 'special' function (i.e. similar to the Euler function or Dirichlet eta function)? Also, how would you prove your original equation (in terms of big O notation)?

Comment: @UNOwen, For your question, again I have no idea and am skeptical about that idea. For your question, you can prove that $$\frac{2\lfloor\log_2 f(m)\rfloor}{f(m)}\cdot\frac{F_{2m+1}}{F_{2m+2}}\sim\frac{2m(\log_2 3 - 1)}{(n+1)(3/2)^m}\cdot\frac{1}{\varphi}=\frac{2(\log_2 3-1)}{(n+1)\varphi} \cdot \frac{m}{(3/2)^m}$$ as $m\to\infty$, where $\varphi$ is the golden ratio.